# Xcode make files open in current window?

Tags: xcode4, customization, new-window

In Xcode 4, whenever I double click on a file, it opens in a new window. I'd rather it open in the existing editor pane instead. Is there an option or something that will let this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like if i single click on a file then that opens it.